# How I modify @Qualifer value at the runtime with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Let's say that I have three beans and a class for test.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("G1")
Public class GlA1 implements GLAInterface {// code...}

@Service
@Qualifier("G2")
Public class GlA2 implements GLAInterface {// code...}

@Service
@Qualifier("G3")
Public class GlA3 implements GLAInterface {// code...}

// the test class

public class Test{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("x") // x = G1 or G2 or G3
private GLAInterface gla;
}
```

And I will not know the value of x until the runtime.
Do you have an idea how to dynamically inject dependencies?

Comment: What info at runtime will allow you to decide which implementation you need ? Is is a variable like the result of a function or is it a property in a config file ? Once you decide, do you always need the same implementation or the others might be used ?

Comment: The customer chooses one of the following 3 classes: GLA1, GLA 2 and GLA3
At the time of the runtime, the customer chooses GLA2 for example suddenly the program must inject GLA2 in gla.
After he can decide to choose another class so on ...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is typically a factory. You should look into the factory design pattern. Let me know if you have any question or need some help.

Comment: @Anne yes it works very well with Factory design pattern thanks. But I am obliged to this in class Test: 

public class Test{
.@Autowired
.@Qualifier("G1") 
private GLAInterface gla;

.@Autowired
.@Qualifier("G2") 
private GLAInterface gla;

.@Autowired
.@Qualifier("G3")
private GLAInterface gla;

}

And I want to do it this way above:

public class Test{
.@Autowired
.@Qualifier("x") //  the client choose if X = G1, G2 or G3
private GLAInterface gla;
}

Thanks for your help

Comment: That's just not possible. Qualifier expects a constant. Spring can not take a var, then change the bean each time the var changes. I don't understand why you can't use your factory in test ?

Comment: Finally I used your method and it works very well and meets my needs. Thanks @Anne

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{
    @Autowired 
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private GLAInterface gla;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
       gla = getGlaBean("G1");
    }

    @Test
    public void aTest2() {
       gla = getGlaBean(System.getenv("GLA_BEAN_NAME"));
    }


    GLAInterface getGlaBean(String name) {
       return (GLAInterface) applicationContext.getBean(name);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If in a second execution the bean we want to inject is G2 and not G1?

Comment: @Test
    public void aTest2() {
       gla = applicationContext.getBean("G2", GlA2.class)
    }


gla will have a new value on each test

Comment: It's specific what you just wrote.
I am looking for a generalized method, for example:

  @Test
    public void aTest(String s) {
       gla = applicationContext.getBean(s, GLAInterface.class);
    }

Comment: No probs:

@Test public void aTest3() { gla = (GLAInterface) applicationContext.getBean("G2") }

Comment: I just executed it ... it does not work.
I have a quick question if you do not mind, you put
gla = (GLAInterface) applicationContext.getBean ("G2")

the value of "G2" is satic, it must be chnageable G1, G2, G100316)

Comment: Sure you can use a variable.

Comment: I have fixed the example above.
Please, have a look.